# RxView with Android Switch

Tags: android, rx-java, android-switch

If for a button, the expression:

```
 yourButton.setOnclicklistener(new .....)
```

can be written with RxJava like:

```
RxView.clicks(yourButton).subscribe(....)
```

I was wondering if for an Android `Switch` the following expression can be written using `RxJava`

Usual version:

```
yourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            }
        });
```

Lambda version:

```
yourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {

        });
```

RxJava version ??????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RxCompoundButton`

Example :

```
RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(your_switch)
            .subscribe(checked -> {
                if (checked){
                    //some code
                }else {
                    //some code
                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks, could you extend a bit? how do i get the checked status of the switch to perform one action or another depending on `isChecked()=true/false`

Comment: RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(binding.settingsSw)
.subscribe(checked->Log.d("A",checked.toString()));

Comment: thanks, accepted answer, also thanks to @DhirajSharma

Comment: This is great, but we don't get access to the button that was clicked like we do with the normal `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. How do I know if the button was pressed when the subscribe action is executed or if the value was changed programmatically?